# Pagination text incorrect in react-data-table-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, react-data-table-component

I have a react parent component which is rendering a Table component which is react-data-table-component. The data is being fetched corrctly but there is pagination footer text problem. There are 26 data. First it is showing 1-10 of 26, then I click next pagination button, it is showing right data but again same 1-10 of 26 but when I click again its getting corrected to 11-20 of 26, but the API is not getting called because the data is correct.

this is the parent component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styles from "../../Components/Scss/Admin.module.scss";
import Table from "../../Components/Global/Table";
import { useAuth } from "../../Context/AuthContext";
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Loader from "../../Components/Global/widget/Loader";
import axios from "axios";
import moment from "moment-timezone";
import CompanyLayout from "../../Components/Company/Layouts";
import Filters from "../../Components/Global/transaction/Filters";
import NoData from "../../Components/Global/widget/NoData";
import { toNumber } from "lodash";
import { HasPermission } from "../../Components/Global/Permission";
import Unauthorised from "../Global/Unauthorised";

import { currencyFormat } from "../../Utils/Common";
import download from "downloadjs";

export default function CustomerDetails({ permission }) {
  const { userInfo, token, selectedStoreIds } = useAuth();
  const [data, setData] = useState(true);
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState();
  const [tips, setTips] = useState();
  const [refund, setRefund] = useState();
  const [salesAmount, setSalesAmount] = useState();
  const [salesPlusFees, setSalesPlusFees] = useState();
  const [salesPlusTips, setSalesPlusTips] = useState();
  const [noOfTransactions, setNoOfTransactions] = useState();
  const [hiddenChart, setHiddenChart] = useState(true);
  const [customer, setCustomer] = useState("");
  const [allTransactionData, setAllTransactionData] = useState();
  const [datePick, setDatePick] = useState();
  const [to, setTo] = useState("");
  const [from, setFrom] = useState("");
  const [totalRows, setTotalRows] = useState();
  const perPage = 10;
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [currentStoreId, setCurrentStoreId] = useState(selectedStoreIds);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [resApiData, setResApiData] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [tableLoading, setTableLoading] = useState(true);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  const getCustomerId = location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1);
  const getTransactions = async () => {
    let userType = "store";
    setTableLoading(true);
    const data = await axios.post(
      `/customer/transctions/list/${getCustomerId}`,
      {
        s: search,
        days: "",
        from: from,
        to: to,
        size: perPage,
        page: currentPage,
        type: userType,
        stores: currentStoreId,
      },
      {
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token },
      }
    );
    if (data && data.data && data.data.response && data.data.response.records) {
      filterData(data.data.response);
      setTotalRows(data.data.response.totalItems);
      setTableLoading(false);
    } else {
      setTableLoading(false);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    //ref.current.continuousStart();
    setCurrentStoreId(selectedStoreIds);
  }, [selectedStoreIds]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (token && currentStoreId) {
      getTransactions();
      let userType = "store";
      setResApiData(false);
      axios
        .post(
          `/customer/transctions/${getCustomerId}`,
          {
            type: userType,
            from: from,
            to: to,
            s: search,
            stores: currentStoreId,
          },
          {
            headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token },
          }
        )
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.data.response) {
            //ref.current.complete();
            setData(false);
            setResApiData(true);
            const transactionsAmountCount = currencyFormat(
              toNumber(response.data.response.metabox.total_order_amount)
            );
            const tipsAmountCount = currencyFormat(
              toNumber(response.data.response.metabox.totaltips)
            );
            const refundAmountCount = currencyFormat(
              toNumber(response.data.response.metabox.returns)
            );
            setNoOfTransactions(
              response.data.response.metabox.noOfTransactions
            );
            setSalesAmount(
              currencyFormat(response.data.response.metabox.salesAmount)
            );
            setSalesPlusFees(
              currencyFormat(response.data.response.metabox.salesPlusFees)
            );
            setSalesPlusTips(
              currencyFormat(response.data.response.metabox.salesPlusTips)
            );
            const getCustomerName = response.data.response.response.fullName;

            setCustomer(getCustomerName);
            setAmount(transactionsAmountCount);
            setTips(tipsAmountCount);
            setRefund(refundAmountCount);
            if (transactionsAmountCount == 0) {
              setData(false);
            } else {
              setData(true);
            }
          } else {
            setData(false);
            setResApiData(true);
          }
        })
        .catch(() => {
          setResApiData(true);
        });
    }
  }, [token, datePick, search, currentStoreId, currentPage]);
  const columns = [
    {
      name: "#",
      selector: (row) => row.serialNo,
      width: "50px",
    },
    {
      name: "Date",
      selector: (row) => row.date,
    },
    {
      name: "Store Name",
      selector: (row) => row.storeName,
      wrap: true,
    },
    {
      name: "Associate Name",
      selector: (row) => row.associate,
      wrap: true,
    },
    {
      name: "Order Amount",
      selector: (row) => row.orderAmount,
    },
    {
      name: "Payment Type",
      selector: (row) => row.paymentType,
      wrap: true,
    },
  ];
  const filterData = (data) => {
    let records = [];
    data.records.map((items, index) => {
      records.push({
        serialNo: index + 1,
        date: moment(items?.transaction.createdAt).format("ll"),
        storeName: items?.transaction?.Store?.store_name,
        associate:
          items?.associate?.first_name + " " + items?.associate?.last_name,
        orderAmount: currencyFormat(toNumber(items?.transaction?.order_amount)),
        paymentType: items?.transaction?.payment_type,
        external_id: items?.transaction?.transactions_external_id,
      });
    });
    setAllTransactionData(records);
  };
  const handleSearchSubmit = async (val) => {
    if (val) {
      setSearch(val);
    }
  };
  const handleDateChange = async (val) => {
    setDatePick(val);
    setFrom(moment(val[0]).startOf("day").format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:SSS"));
    setTo(moment(val[1]).startOf("day").format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:SSS"));
  };
  const onRowClick = (val) => {
    navigate(`/transaction/${val.external_id}`);
  };
  const handleOnPageChange = async (val) => {
    if (val) {
      setCurrentPage(val);
    }
  };
  const quarries = {
    stores: currentStoreId,
    customer_external_id: getCustomerId,
    from: from,
    to: to,
  };
  const handleDownload = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const data = await axios.post(
        "/download/transaction/report/customer",
        quarries,
        {
          responseType: "blob",
          headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token },
        }
      );
      setLoading(false);
      download(
        data.data,
        `Customer transactions reports ${moment(new Date()).format(
          "MMMM Do YYYY"
        )}`
      );
    } catch (e) {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  const HandelHiddenChart = (e) => {
    const hiddenChartVal = e.target.checked;
    setHiddenChart(hiddenChartVal);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {/*<LoadingBar color="#1c8e44" loaderSpeed={1500} height={2} ref={ref} shadow={false} className={"mt-[72px]"}/>*/}
      {loading && <Loader />}
      {HasPermission(permission) ? (
        <CompanyLayout onStoreChange={(val) => setCurrentStoreId(val)}>
          <div>
            {resApiData ? (
              <div className="px-5 pt-4 bg-slate-100 rounded-xl">
                <div className="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between pb-4">
                  <div>
                    <p className="text-xl md:text-3xl font-bold text-gray-700 capitalize">
                      {customer ? customer.toLowerCase() : ""}
                    </p>
                    <p className="mt-2 mb-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-500">
                      Registration Date & Time:{" "}
                      <span className="text-gray-700 border-gray-400">
                        {moment(userInfo.createdAt).format("ll LT")}
                      </span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="flex">
                    <div className="flex items-center mr-3">
                      <p className="pr-2 text-gray-600">
                        {hiddenChart ? "Disable" : "Enable"} Chart
                      </p>

                      <div className={`${styles.switch_box}`}>
                        <input
                          type="checkbox"
                          id="HiddenChartId"
                          defaultChecked={hiddenChart}
                          name="HiddenChartId"
                          onChange={(e) => HandelHiddenChart(e)}
                          className={` ${styles.input_switch}`}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="HiddenChartId" className={``} />
                        <div className={` ${styles.switch_status_box}`}></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className="">
                  {hiddenChart && (
                    <div className="grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-4 gap-3 pt-4 pb-4 border-t">
                      <div className="flex items-center p-3 bg-white rounded">
                        <div className="ml-3">
                          <p className="text-xs tracking-wide text-gray-500">
                            Sales Amount:
                          </p>
                          <p className="mt-1 text-base font-semibold text-gray-700">
                            {salesAmount}
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="flex items-center p-3 bg-white rounded">
                        <div className="ml-3">
                          <p className="text-xs tracking-wide text-gray-500">
                            Tips:
                          </p>
                          <p className="mt-1 text-base font-semibold text-gray-700">
                            {tips}
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="flex items-center p-3 bg-white rounded">
                        <div className="ml-3">
                          <p className="text-xs tracking-wide text-gray-500">
                            Sales Amount + Tips:
                          </p>
                          <p className="mt-1 text-base font-semibold text-gray-700">
                            {salesPlusTips}
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div className="flex items-center p-3 bg-white rounded">
                        <div className="ml-3">
                          <p className="text-xs tracking-wide text-gray-500">
                            Total Amount + Fees:
                          </p>
                          <p className="mt-1 text-base font-semibold text-gray-700">
                            {salesPlusFees}
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="flex items-center p-3 bg-white rounded">
                        <div className="ml-3">
                          <p className="text-xs tracking-wide text-gray-500">
                            Total Processed:
                          </p>
                          <p className="mt-1 text-base font-semibold text-gray-700">
                            {amount}
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div className="flex items-center p-3 bg-white rounded">
                        <div className="ml-3">
                          <p className="text-xs tracking-wide text-gray-500">
                            Number of Transactions:
                          </p>
                          <p className="mt-1 text-base font-semibold text-gray-700">
                            {" "}
                            {noOfTransactions}
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div className="flex items-center p-3 bg-white rounded">
                        <div className="ml-3">
                          <p className="text-xs tracking-wide text-gray-500">
                            Returns:
                          </p>
                          <p className="mt-1 text-base font-semibold text-gray-700">
                            {" "}
                            {refund}
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div className="px-5 pt-4 bg-slate-100 rounded-xl animate-pulse">
                <div className="flex items-center justify-between pb-4 border-b">
                  <div>
                    <p className="h-6 rounded bg-slate-300 w-36 "></p>
                    <p className="h-3 mt-2 rounded bg-slate-300 w-60"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <div className="inline-flex px-10 py-4 rounded bg-slate-300"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-3 pt-4 pb-4 border-t">
                  {Array.from(Array(6), (e, i) => {
                    return (
                      <div
                        key={i}
                        className="flex items-center p-3 rounded bg-white/75"
                      >
                        {/* <div className="w-12 h-12 p-2 bg-slate-200 rounded-xl"></div> */}
                        <div className="ml-3">
                          <p className="w-20 h-2 rounded bg-slate-200 "></p>
                          <p className="w-10 h-4 mt-2 rounded bg-slate-200"></p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
                </div>
              </div>
            )}

            <div className="items-center pt-7">
              <h5 className="mt-4 md:mt-8 mb-4 text-xl font-semibold text-gray-700">
                All Transaction
              </h5>
              <div className="">
                <Filters
                  placeHolder={"Search"}
                  enableSearch={false}
                  download={true}
                  onDownload={handleDownload}
                  downloadBtn={true}
                  date={handleDateChange}
                  onSearchSubmit={handleSearchSubmit}
                  onSearchReset={() => setSearch("")}
                  downloadBtnDisable={allTransactionData}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            {data ? (
              <div>
                <div className={`${styles.table_ui_style}`}>
                  <Table
                    pending={tableLoading}
                    data={allTransactionData}
                    columns={columns}
                    totalRows={totalRows}
                    showPointer={true}
                    onRowClick={(val) => onRowClick(val)}
                    onPageChange={handleOnPageChange}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <NoData />
            )}
          </div>
        </CompanyLayout>
      ) : (
        <Unauthorised />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

This is the table component

```
import React from "react";
import DataTable from "react-data-table-component";
import { customStyles } from "./CustomTableStyle";
import LoadingTable from "./LoadingTable";
import NoData from "./widget/NoData";

function Table({
  columns,
  data,
  totalRows,
  onPageChange,
  showPointer,
  onRowClick,
  showPagination = true,
  perPage = 20,
  pending,
  conditionalRowStyles,
  handleSort,
}) {
  return (
    <div className={`dash-table pt-2 md:pt-5`}>
      <>
        {!showPointer ? (
          <DataTable
            columns={columns}
            data={data}
            highlightOnHover={true}
            defaultSortAsc={false}
            striped={false}
            pagination={showPagination}
            paginationServer={true}
            paginationTotalRows={totalRows}
            customStyles={customStyles}
            paginationPerPage={perPage}
            paginationRowsPerPageOptions={[]}
            onChangePage={(val) => onPageChange(val)}
            paginationComponentOptions={{ noRowsPerPage: true }}
            onColumnOrderChange={true}
            progressPending={pending}
            progressComponent={<LoadingTable />}
            noDataComponent={<NoData />}
            conditionalRowStyles={conditionalRowStyles}
            onSort={handleSort}
            fixedHeader
          />
        ) : (
          <>
            <DataTable
              className="pagenation"
              columns={columns}
              data={data}
              highlightOnHover={true}
              defaultSortAsc={false}
              striped={false}
              pagination={showPagination}
              paginationServer={true}
              paginationTotalRows={totalRows}
              customStyles={customStyles}
              paginationPerPage={perPage}
              paginationRowsPerPageOptions={[]}
              onChangePage={(val) => onPageChange(val)}
              paginationComponentOptions={{ noRowsPerPage: true }}
              onRowClicked={(val) => onRowClick(val)}
              pointerOnHover={true}
              onColumnOrderChange={true}
              progressPending={pending}
              progressComponent={<LoadingTable />}
              noDataComponent={<NoData />}
              conditionalRowStyles={conditionalRowStyles}
              onSort={handleSort}
              fixedHeader
            />
            {/* <LoadingTable /> */}
          </>
        )}
      </>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Table;
```

First load -- Page 1 (Correct)
[image]

After clicking the next button -- Page 2 (Data is correct but the pagination details is not)
[image]

After clicking the next button again -- Page 2 (showing correct pagination data)
[image]

Comment: Anyone?? Its pretty tough here....